# Longest satisfied continuous subarray

Tags: algorithm

A is a array, B is the prime factors order of all the elements in A, `size(A)=N (1<=N<=30000)`,`size(B)=M (1<=M<=30)`, the question is just find the longest continuous subarray whose accumulate is a square number. Next is a example

```
 Input(condition):
     A={4,9,25,6}     B={2,3,5}       size(A)=N=4      size(B)=M=3
 Output:
     {4，9，25}
 Reason:
     the continuous subarray's accmulate must be a square number, so in A, there 6 subarraies,
    {4}           4=2^2
    {9}           9=3^2
    {25}          25=5^2
    {4,9}         4*9=6^2
    {9,25}        9*25=15^2
    {4,9,25}      4*9*25=30^2
    but we want find the longest one, that means the size of subarray must be bigest, so the result is {4,9,25}.
```

I have no thought about it up to now, so there is no achievement, but I promise I have think about it for a long time, hope a help, Thanks !

Comment: And your problem is ...?

Comment: the question is just find the longest continuous subarray whose accumulate is a square number

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I guess you need to get the idea of "maximum continuous subarray" algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) and then just modify it a little bit to fit your problem.

Comment: @DanKruchinin These are two very different problems. I don't think you can modify the max-subarray algorithm "a little".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add some details to Klas Lindbäck's answer and suggest a possible solution.

Firstly, we will accumulate the product up to position `i` and store the prime factor decomposition in the array `partialPrimes`. This array will only contain whether the exponent is even (0) or odd (1) as a bit field as suggested by Klas Lindbäck.

So `partialPrimes[0]` will contain the decomposition of `A[0]`. `partialPrimes[1]` will contain the decomposition of `A[0] * A[1]` and so on.

Furthermore, we store a map of the maximum index for a given decomposition.

```
int partialPrimes[N]
lastPartialPrimes := 0
maxPrime = new Map<int, int>
for i from 0 to N - 1
    int primes = calculatePrimeDecomposition(A[i], B)
    partialPrimes[i] = lastPartialPrimes xor primes
    lastPartialPrimes = primes
    maxPrime[primes] = i
next
```

The prime decomposition can be found by successively dividing by the given prime factors and xor-ing the according bit.

Now to check if all factors have even exponents (and therefore if the number is a square number) we can simply compare the decomposition to 0.

To get the decomposition of a partial product, we can subtract the decompositions at the according indices. So e.g. to calculate the decomposition of the product `A[4] * A[5] * A[6] * A[7]` we could just calculate `partialPrimes[7] - partialPrimes[3]` (index at end - index before).

So to find the range where the product is a square number, we need to find equal `partialPrimes`:

```
int maxLength = -1
int start = -1, end = -1
for i from 0 to N - 1
    //check if this product is already a square number
    if(partialPrimes[i] == 0 && maxLength < i + 1) 
    {
        maxLength = i + 1
        start = 0
        end = i
    }
    //is there a equal decomposition?
    else if maxPrime.contains(partialPrimes[i])
    {
        int newEnd = maxPrime[partialPrimes[i]]
        int newStart = i + 1
        int newLength = newEnd - newStart + 1
        if(newLength > maxLength)
        {
            start = newStart
            end = newEnd
            maxLength = newLength
        }
    }
next
```

The code is just used to illustrate the overall idea and may contain minor mistakes.

If we assume that the prime factor decomposition takes `O(d)` time, then the overall time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n * d)`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the whole answer, but it should get you going:

The accumulate is a square number if each prime factor accurs an even number of times.

So, for each possible subarray, count the occurrence of yeach prime factor. If the occurrence for each factor is even, then the accumulate of the subarray is a square number.

Optimisation hint:

For an optimised solution, store the prime factorisation as 32-bit numbers with bit=1 denoting an odd number and bit=0 an even number and then XOR:ing them together. If the total is 0, then the accumulate is a square number.

Comment: The trivial algorithm (checking all subarrays) is `O(N^2*M)`.